# Stack Overflow user profile page doesn't want to link to Careers

Tags: support, jobs, profile-page

It seems like it should now be possible for my Stack Overflow profile to link to Stack Overflow Careers, but somehow it doesn't show my profile (even though clicking the link next to it does get me to my Careers profile). Any clues?

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/198954

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/djc (is 404, maybe this is related?)

Comment: Try toggling your careers CV from private to public and back. Give it a few seconds then check your edit page.

Comment: It seemed to already find my page when I got back to the profile, then it gave me the option of making my Careers profile public, which seemed to Just Work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is how I did that:

1. After logging in go to my Stack Overflow dashboard by clicking on my **profile picture on top.**
2. Click on **Edit CV** link from my dashboard
3. Click on **Settings** button from the right side.
4. Type my user name (e.g. siddiquinoor) to generate my link and click on **Make Public** button.

Now I can see my profile page in any of the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/cv/siddiquinoor
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/siddiquinoor