# Associate my Careers profile with SO profile

Tags: support, jobs, profile-page, user-accounts

On my SO profile (this is the new, recently released one), in the Web Presence section, it says that there's no Careers profile for this account, and to click the link (Discover StackOverflow Careers) to find out more.

I have a StackOverflow Careers account, and when I click the link it logs me straight in to my account.

Have I messed things up somehow - perhaps they are somehow two different accounts, and I'm logged in to both of them? If so, how can I associate my SO Careers account with my SO account?

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround, in a comment to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253610/stack-overflow-user-profile-page-doesnt-want-to-link-to-careers) question. I set my Careers profile to private, then to public, waited a few seconds, then refreshed my SO profile. The SO Careers profile is now there.

Comment: I don't see any option to set my Careers profile visibility